# Access X and Y coordinate data using an array - CHART.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

In my project, I have X and Y coordinate motion that allows the car to move.
I want to be able to put this data into an array because I want to move a steering wheel to see where the car is going.
However, for this, I need to be able to refer to the previous and next data.
Can anyone help?

```
tag5617.subscribe(function(message) {
  let X = document.getElementById('posX');
  X.innerHTML = message.x.toFixed(2);
  let Y = document.getElementById('posY');
  Y.innerHTML = message.y.toFixed(2);
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
    x: message.x.toFixed(2),
    y: message.y.toFixed(2)
  });
  myChart.update();
});
```