# Reference to the previous element in the array - in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

How can I refer to the previous element in an array?
I want to calculate the angular distance of 2 coordinates so that I can move a steering wheel.
My data comes from a robot.

```
let arrX = [];
let arrY = [];
tag5617.subscribe(function(message) {

    let X = document.getElementById('posX');

    X.innerHTML = message.x.toFixed(2);


    let Y = document.getElementById('posY');

    Y.innerHTML = message.y.toFixed(2);
   
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push({x:message.x.toFixed(2), y:message.y.toFixed(2)});

    arrX.push(message.x);
    arrY.push(message.y);


    let deg = Math.atan2(message.x - arrX[-1], message.y - arrY[-1]) * 180 / Math.PI;


    myChart.update();

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access X and Y coordinate data using an array - CHART.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754613/access-x-and-y-coordinate-data-using-an-array-chart-js)

Comment: @LeeLenalee There's no answer there.

Comment: No but reposting your own question is also not the way to go

Answer (score 0):

After you push a new element onto an array, the element before it is the 2nd to last element.

Unlike some other languages (e.g. Python) there's no shorthand syntax to index from the end of an array. So you have to calculate the index by subtracting from `array.length`.

```
let deg = Math.atan2(message.x - arrX[arrX.length-2], message.y - arrY[arrY.length-2]) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Comment: _"there's no shorthand syntax to index from the end"_ -> [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at): _"The `at()` method takes an integer value and returns the item at that index, allowing for positive and negative integers. Negative integers count back from the last item in the array."_

Comment: Thanks. That appears to be fairly new, and it's still not supported on all common platforms (e.g. iOS Safari).